# Reference request: Constituents of a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

Reading several papers by Lux and Szőke, I have come across the notion of a *constituent* of an $A$-module $M$, where $A$ is an algebra over a field. I did not find a clear definition; in Burrow's *Representation theory of finite groups*, at least *top* and *bottom constituents* are defined. But what is a constitient of a module in general?

My guess would be that if I write down a sequence $0\subsetneq M_1 \subsetneq\cdots\subsetneq M_\ell=M$ of proper submodule inclusions, then I would call any subquotient $M_i/M_{i-1}$ a constituent; so the notion of a constituent generalises the notion of a composition factor. In fact, irreducible constituents then would be the same as composition factors. Is this guess of the definition of a constituent correct?

Comment: From memory they use the term "constituent" to mean a composition factor, so "constituent" means "irreducible constituent".